# the likelihood of being one of three daughters and then having three daughters

Tags: probability

I am not a statistics person myself, so I don't know of a more technical way to word it, but let me explain what I'm trying to get at.  I am one of three biological children, all female.  No other siblings.  Just us three girls.

I now am a mother, and I also have three children, all female. I would like to find out what the probability is of that occurring--being one of three daughters and then giving birth to three daughters. This does not have to be 100% accurate--I'm just looking for the best answer you can come up with.

Comment: Are you assuming each probability is .5 & they are all independent?

Comment: Do you mean having only three daughter, without male siblings? The same question applied to being one of three daughters.

Comment: Assuming "statistical likelihood" means "chance" or "probability," the answer must depend on some set of assumptions and a context. What kind of people would this chance apply to? Living where, during which time? What characteristics would they have in terms of age, sexual orientation, or anything else that might be related to this chance? As @Erik asks, precisely what event are you trying to describe?

Comment: I voted to reopen. The event is still undefined, but a good instructive answer would explain why a probability cannot be just given without further specifying the assumptions and context, and perhaps consider the probabilities of various different events related to the question).

Comment: According to the information given, there is a 100% chance that you are one of three daughters and you gave birth to three daughters. Obviously that's uninformative--but to get any more information out, *you have to put more in*.  Unless you provide an explicit description of the event you are trying to assess, just about any answer greater than 0% will be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both you and your mother were going to have exactly 3 children, then the odds are simply (1/2)^6 or about 1.56%.

However, if we multiply in the odds of having 3 children (much less common today than in your mother's) it becomes smaller.  Furthermore, the odds of conception are actually slightly skewed towards males (more are conceived, but more are stillborn and die in childbirth), so that drops the odds a bit.

You could also make it more complicated by asking the odds of any of her 3 daughters having exactly 3 daughters (increases the odds).  Assuming all had 3 children, then you would have (1/2)^3 for your mother's 3 daughters times 1 - (odds of not 3 daughters)^3:

$$P=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 * \left(1-\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3\right)^3\right)$$
$$P\approx 0.0413$$

about 4%

Comment: You need to be very, very clear about your assumptions, for otherwise the results will be questionable (to those who know better) or confusing (to those who don't). For instance, your initial calculation seems to include the possibility that the OP is not female, even though she describes herself as a mother.

Comment: good point!  Yes, I left in the 50% chance of her not being female since theoretically none of what occurred had to happen